Envoy not sending authentication header in grpc request to google cloud run instance
I am trying to build a service discovery system on the google cloud platform. I chose to use envoy as the data plane and implemented a 'custom' control plane using go-control-plane. Everything works locally. In the cloud environment I'm deploying the envoy-proxy and the control-plane on separate google cloud run instances. The envoy-proxy will then use ADS to stream clusters and listener configuration from the control-plane. For my initial test I disabled the authentication requirement on the control plane and the envoy-proxy was able to communicate and stream the configuration from the control-plane. The issue is when I add back the authentication fails with a 401 error claiming that the envoy-proxy google cloud run instance is not allowed to call the control-plane.
I then turned to the envoy documentation. I am using the google grpc client in the envoy-proxy configuration since the default envoy-client just did not work at all on google cloud. Below is a snippet of the envoy-proxy config file. The channel credentials are so that I can use TLS, which is required for the google cloud run with gRPC due to it being required for HTTP/2.
dynamic_resources:
  ads_config:
    api_type: GRPC
    transport_api_version: V3
    grpc_services:
    - google_grpc:
        target_uri: service-mesh-control-registry-wq6aarbnaq-ez.a.run.app:443
        stat_prefix: control-registry
        channel_credentials:
          ssl_credentials:
            root_certs:
              filename: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

I noticed that I needed to add the call-credentials configuration, which has the following options as described in the docs. First I tried the google-compute-engine option naively as shown below:
dynamic_resources:
  ads_config:
    api_type: GRPC
    transport_api_version: V3
    grpc_services:
    - google_grpc:
        target_uri: service-mesh-control-registry-wq6aarbnaq-ez.a.run.app:443
        stat_prefix: control-registry
        call_credentials:
           google_compute_engine: {}
        channel_credentials:
          ssl_credentials:
            root_certs:
              filename: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

I can't share the exact screenshots, but the error messages on the control-plane show that something tried to call it and it returned a 401 error. This authentication check is happening at the google cloud run load balancer level.
Next I tried to read the token from a file. The way I did this is by adjusting the script I use to run docker to first send a cURL to the internal metadata server of the cloud run instance for a token.
entrypoint script snippet
This does however have the obvious flaw of handling token expiration, but I just wanted to try something. This also gave the exact same result as google compute engine configuration.
Something I did not try is setting the initial metadata, but once again I don't want to have to handle the token refresh myself. Any suggestions or insight would be welcome, if the solution is to write a new plugin then that's fine, I just want to know that I've tried everything.

It seems the image are not loading for some reason

Just going to leave this comment here for the people that have a similar issue. So the solution is unfortunately to use an internal listener for the outgoing request so we can use this filter https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/gcp_authn_filter to attach the token. An example of how to setup an internal listener is described in the envoy docs as well: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/other_features/internal_listener.html#internal-listener
